# Why is Joule heating (or electric power) proportional to current squared?

Tags: power, heat, ohms-law

I know, that the formula P = R·I<sup>2</sup> is derived from the formula of electric power and Ohm's Law, but the intuition behind why the current is exactly squared here is unclear to me.

I get that the more charged particles pass through a given cross-section of a conductor, the more the chance of them colliding with each other and with atomic nuclei, but why is the chance squared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a resistance, when you double the voltage across it, you also double the current. That's embodied in Ohm's law \$I = \frac{V}{R}\$.

When you double the voltage, you double the potential energy that each charge possesses, that it will deliver to the environment (as heat) on its journey between the two points of potential difference (each end of the resistor).

That doubling of potential difference also doubles the strength of the electric field between those two points of differing potential. Force on each charge is therefore also doubled, the average charge velocity is doubled, and twice as many charges make the journey each second. In other words, current also doubled.

Now you have two factors to consider when voltage and current are doubled:

1. Charges start the journey with twice as much potential energy to donate to the environment.
2. Charges are moving twice as fast, on average, so twice as many charges are completing the journey each second.

That's a factor of four increase in energy being delivered to the environment each second, otherwise known as power.

Answer (score 2):

Joule heating is proportional to V.I. Always. Without qualification.

In the specific case of Ohm's Law being obeyed, that is a component with a constant resistance (which is often approximately true, but many times is not), then V = R.I, and so power = I<sup>2</sup>.R

'Resistors' are components carefully designed to have a fairly constant resistance. Ordinary metals have quite a high temperature coefficient of resistance, so the exponent for I is quite different to 2 in the case of plain metallic resistors. The stereotype for this is the tungsten filament bulb, where the resistance changes by an order of magnitude between cold and working temperature.

> I get that the more charged particles pass through a given cross-section of a conductor, the more the chance of them colliding with each other and with atomic nuclei, but why is the chance squared?

It's best not to think of charged particles rushing about, it's not a good model for understanding things like potential, the voltage term, which is equally as important as the current.

Comment: So do I get correctly, that P is always proportional to V*I, not necessairly equal? And furthermore, V is not necessairly equal to R*I, even if the Ohm's Law is being obeyed?

Comment: Your premise is only correct for non-reactive (real) impedances. More generally, power is always equal to VI. But how much power actually turns into Joule heating does depend on the impedance.

Comment: @Andrew'sQuest, Not just proportional. Equal. The instantaneous power (in watts) that is delivered to a two-terminal circuit element always is _equal_ to the product of the voltage between its terminals and the current (in amperes) through its terminals in that same instant. The power that is _dissipated as heat_ in the device might not be equal because some of that power may be used for some other purpose (e.g., to make light, to force an electrochemical reaction, to turn the shaft of a motor, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

At an "intuitive level", you could view resistive power dissipation as being caused by charge carriers impacting with fixed atoms, losing their kinetic energy, and leading to heat generation.

Charge "velocity" is proportional to current, and kinetic energy of each carrier is proportional to velocity squared, so the energy lost to each collision is proportional to current squared.

Reality is really rather different to the above "analysis", but the physics leads to the same square dependency on current for a given fixed resistance.

Comment: Your analogy definetely helps! Can you please specify, at least, in what direction is the reality different from the model, given by you?

Comment: A big difference is that the electrons have a base velocity related to thermal motion and temperature, even if there is no current.  This means the very simplistic analysis isn't valid. You also have to remember that for electrons, wave-particle duality is a major factor.

Comment: so I² embodies "velocity" of current, not of an electron? And does base velocity of electrons relate somehow to thermoinduced current? Greatly appreciate your answers.

Comment: At a broad level yes, but I wouldn't take the analogy too far.